# starting Neural OCR recognition in Matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network, ocr

I'm trying to implement  a basic OCR programming using Neural Networks in MatLab.I've understood the examples at the MathWorks website,but I'm still not sure how to input my own dataset to the nprtool for neural networks .
1.How would I create my own dataset consisting of digits or where can I get datasets on the net .
2.After training the neural network ,how do I get MATLAB to recognize a character from an image .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find a dataset of images of digits online from the MNIST database [here](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/).

Typically, in Matlab, you will need to process each digit image to convert the entire matrix of image pixels into a vector of pixels (or some kind of feature from your image).  Each digit image will have its own input vector of features associated with it.

You will train your neural network by appending many of these feature vectors together into a training matrix (typically of size numImages x numFeatures).  Once your network is trained, you can supply a new feature vector from any digit image and the network will process it and return its predicted output.

You might also refer to this [Kaggle Competition](http://www.kaggle.com/c/digit-recognizer) on digit recognition for further assistance.